# How can we add a space between nomineeFirstName and nomineeLastName while iterating in react hooks page

Tags: reactjs

How can we add a space between `nomineeFirstName` and `nomineeLastName` while iterating in react hooks page. I have tried to add a space in between, but it doesn't work.

```
const [nominationGroup, setNominationGroup] = useState({});

if (isMounted.current) {
          for (const elem of res.data) {
            if (!newGroup.hasOwnProperty(elem.nomineeFirstName + " " +elem.nomineeLastName)) {
              newGroup[elem.nomineeFirstName + elem.nomineeLastName] = {
                createdAt: "",
                reason: [],
              };
            }
            newGroup[elem.nomineeFirstName + elem.nomineeLastName].reason.push(elem.reason);
            newGroup[elem.nomineeFirstName + elem.nomineeLastName].createdAt = elem.createdAt;
          }
          setNominationGroup(newGroup);
          console.log("Nomination data from server :" + res.data);
        } 



{Object.keys(nominationGroup).map((nomineename) => (
    <div className='wrap'>
      <div key={nomineename} id='sidebar-left'>
        {nomineename}
      </div>
      <div id='main-content'>
        {nominationGroup[nomineename].reason.map((desc) => (
          <li key={desc} className='nomlistdata'>
            <li>{desc}</li>
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div key={nominationGroup[nomineename].createdAt} id='sidebar-right'>
        {moment(nominationGroup[nomineename].createdAt).format(
          "DD-MMM-YYYY"
        )}
      </div>
      <hr></hr>
    </div>
  ))}
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-cache-3rqmj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Are you referencing this `newGroup[elem.nomineeFirstName + elem.nomineeLastName]`?

Comment: Yes...I have tried this was..but the whole data stop dispalying... ``newGroup[elem.nomineeFirstName + " " + elem.nomineeLastName] = {
                createdAt: "",
                reason: [],
              };``

Comment: @Ameer I have tried this way..please see my reply above..

Comment: Where are you trying to add a space between these two values? Here `newGroup[elem.nomineeFirstName + elem.nomineeLastName]`? Please clarify what isn't working.

Comment: Yes ..here ``newGroup[elem.nomineeFirstName + elem.nomineeLastName]``` Now it firstname and lastname displayed together.

Comment: Are you just trying to create a computed property? What isn't working when you `newGroup[elem.nomineeFirstName + " " + elem.nomineeLastName]`?

Comment: When i added space ``+ "  " +`` The whole data is not showing in the above table... ( I have added the screenshot for reference)

Comment: This isn't a complete and reproducible code example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If you are adding a space to any computed properties then you need to consistently add a space when later computing property keys to reference into your `nominationGroup` state. You may also have better luck using `Object.entries` when converting your state to an array to be mapped.

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry i forgot to add the codesandbox example for reference...kindly have a look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are not consistently computing a property.

When you check if `newGroup` has the property already you are correctly computing a property with a space:

```
if (newGroup.hasOwnProperty(
  elem.nomineeFirstName + " " + elem.nomineeLastName
))
```

But then immediately in this if block use a malformed key to create a new group:

```
newGroup[elem.nomineeFirstName + elem.nomineeLastName] = {
  createdAt: "",
  reason: []
};
```

Since `newGroup` ***never*** has a computed property with a space a new object is created for each `elem` in `data` that is iterated over.

## Solution

I suggest creating the computed key first, then referring to this key in the for-of loop.

```
for (const elem of myData) {
  const key = elem.nomineeFirstName + " " + elem.nomineeLastName;
  if (!newGroup.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    newGroup[key] = {
      createdAt: "",
      reason: []
    };
  }
  newGroup[key].reason.push(elem.reason);
  newGroup[key].createdAt = elem.createdAt;
}
setNominationGroup(newGroup);
```

It would better to use a `reduce` to loop over the `myData` array and reduce it into an object.

```
const newGroup = myData.reduce((newGroup, elem) => {
  const key = elem.nomineeFirstName + " " + elem.nomineeLastName;
  if (!newGroup.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    newGroup[key] = {
      createdAt: "",
      reason: []
    };
  }
  newGroup[key].reason.push(elem.reason);
  newGroup[key].createdAt = elem.createdAt;
  return newGroup;
}, {});
setNominationGroup(newGroup);
```

[image: Edit how-can-we-add-a-space-between-nomineefirstname-and-nomineelastname-while-iterat]

Comment: Wonderful anwser, totally agree to this point >> ".... computed key first, then referring to this key " Upvoted and accepted

Comment: Could you please help me with this one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69330947/in-my-react-hooks-when-i-click-on-button-how-can-i-plot-the-data-over-every-mont